# how to set a button at the bottom of a screen when the parent is a scroll view?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a scrollView (this is a solution to support landscape computability)

and in it one child- linearLayout.

I want to pose a button at the bottom of a screen.

`layout_height = match_parent` is problematic as the scroll can be infinite.

How can I do this, to be compatible to all screen resolution?

this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.m"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue_bg" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.m.view.text.mTextView
            android:id="@+id/verifyHeaderText"
            style="@style/textOnBg"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="ENTER VERIFICATION CODE"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:font_type="varela" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                android:paddingRight="25dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/inputBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_box_idle"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/verificationCodeEditText"
                        style="@style/textOnBg"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:hint="-  -  -  -  -"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="5"
                        android:textColor="#00bcfe"
                        android:textSize="25dp"
                        android:textStyle="italic" >
                    </EditText>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/continueButton"
                style="@style/textOnBg"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
                android:text="Continue"
                android:textColor="#00bcfe"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

this is the result on wide-screen

[image]
The button is in the bottom of the scroll which spans 3/4 of the whole screen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add android:fillViewport="true" to your scrollview:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.m"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue_bg"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
```

Comment: super. btw, how could I have done this if my <button> would have been a child of `+@id/rootLayout` and had a property `
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"`? it didn't work for me

Comment: try to make use of linear layout's weight attribute, for example set weight of the relative layout to 1.0 and weight of the button to 0.0 (of course keep the fillViewport="true" for the scrollview)

Comment: `android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal` shouldn't work?

Comment: I may be wrong but it looks like layout_gravity="bottom" doesn't work when the orientation of the linear layout is set to vertical

Answer (score 0):

Apply this to your layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Your scroll view -->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/ar_button_height"
        android:gravity="center" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_at_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/ar_button_height"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:showDividers="middle" >
        </Button>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a better solution, but you could put your scroll view inside a relative layout and have your button outside the scroll view and set `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` on the button

Comment: but that's not what I want. I want the whole screen to be scrollable

Comment: Oh ok. Try using `android:fillViewport="true"` on your scroll view. This should make it fill the height on the screen

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the button at the bottom you need to implement your layout with weight.
First of all the scrollview can only have one child layout inside it.
Secondly add your content layout inside the child layout of it, set the layout_height to 0dp, and do remember to set the weight to 1.
And at last add your button at the bottom of your content layout and set its height and set the weight to be 0.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollMain"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:overScrollMode="always"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:scrollbars="none">
       <LinearLayout
                android:overScrollMode="always"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </LinearLayout>
            <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="0" />
        </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: scrollView disorder the layout_weight as well. It can be infinite high, so the weight cannot be calculated

Comment: why don't you implement the button outside of the scroll view and set the scroll view height to be 0?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.m.view.text.mTextView
        android:id="@+id/verifyHeaderText"
        style="@style/textOnBg"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="ENTER VERIFICATION CODE"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:font_type="varela" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
            android:paddingRight="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/inputBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/input_box_idle"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/verificationCodeEditText"
                    style="@style/textOnBg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:hint="-  -  -  -  -"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="5"
                    android:textColor="#00bcfe"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    android:textStyle="italic" >
                </EditText>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/continueButton"
            style="@style/textOnBg"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
            android:text="Continue"
            android:textColor="#00bcfe"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
```

> USe your button here

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrollView inside relativeLayout to fix your button at bottom:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/radialback">


    <ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_header"
        >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editmessage"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        style="@style/editView"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 _-.,()"
        android:maxLength="500"
        />
     </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/submitbutton"
    android:text="@string/submitbutton"
    style="@style/submitView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```